# Duplicates needed as well as latest date

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL-Server Enterprise Version 8.0.
I have this query that's becoming incredibly complicated that is not giving me the results I need.  The query runs but I get no results with the addition of the latest date.

There are three main problems so far.

Basically, I need to find duplicate names in a database and identifying information about them.  Preferably, I'd like to put the duplicate name columns and addresses next to each other so it can be compared as many times as they appear in the database.  So, if a name is repeated 3 times in the database, I'd like for there to be a C1 name, C2 name and C3 name.

I'd also like to join other tables so I can get information such as child's name and what the latest activity (the subquery) on the client was.

Problem #1: The natural join is not working here in combination with the left outer joins. Do I need to use a union?

Problem #2: I am trying to get the Most Recent Activity.  While the Case..When works alone, when put in together with the rest of the query (minus the left outer joins) does not produce any results.  Ideally, I'd like the Most Recent Activity to be returned for each contact, C1 and C2 in the select.  I used the contactid but maybe that's not what I'm supposed to use?

Problem #3: If a name appears more than 2 times in the database, I'm getting all sorts of combinations for them in different rows.  How can I get them in the result list to appear as one row and not multiple combinations?  Do I need to add C3?  There as many as 7 and 8 duplicate names..how do I keep the query from becoming more cumbersome?  Are there any other ways to do this?

To provide an example, I'd like the results to appear as such:

'ContactID 1', 'ContactID 2', 'ContactID 3','Last Name', 'First Name', 'Contact 1 Address', 'Contact 2 Address', 'Contact 3 Address', 'C1 Home phone and Work phone', 'C2 Home phone and Work phone', 
'C3 Home phone and Work phone', 'C1 Child's Name','C2 Child's Name', 'C3 Child's Name', 'C1 Most Recent Activity', 'C2 Most Recent Activity', 'C3 Most Recent Activity'

I would reduce the query to basics to keep it simple, but at this point, I don't know what to leave out.  Forgive the cumbersome query and I appreciate you taking the time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (c1.contactid) as 'ContactID 1', (c2.contactid) as 'ContactID 2', c1.lastname as
  'Last Name', c1.firstname as 'First Name', 
  (c1.address+' '+c1.city+', '+ c1.state +' '+ c1.postalcode) as 'Contact 1 Address', 
  (c2.address+' '+c2.city+', '+ c2.state +' '+ c2.postalcode) as 'Contact 2 Address', 
  (c1.homephone+' '+ c1.workphone) as 'C1 Home phone and Work phone', 
  (c2.homephone+' '+ c2.workphone) as 'C2 Home phone and Work phone',
  (cg.childfirst+' ' +cg.childlast) as 'C1 Child''s Name',
  (cv.childfirst+ ' '+cv.childlast) as 'C2 Child''s Name'
FROM contacts c1, contacts c2 
WHERE (c1.child=0) and (c1.contactid<c2.contactid) and ((c1.lastname + c1.firstname)=  
  (c2.lastname + c2.firstname))
LEFT OUTER JOIN caregiverlabel cg on c1.contactid=cg.contactid,
  contacts c2
LEFT OUTER JOIN caregiverlabel cv on c2.contactid=cv.contactid
  AND c1.contactid IN 
   (SELECT max(MostRecentActivity) 
   FROM (select case
            WHEN c1.modifieddate >= sl.starttime AND c1.modifieddate >= cl.createdate   
                    AND c1.modifieddate >= pr.created AND c1.modifieddate >= pm.created THEN 
                    c1.modifieddate
                    WHEN sl.starttime >= c1.modifieddate AND sl.starttime >= cl.createdate AND 
                    sl.starttime >= pr.created AND sl.starttime >= pm.created THEN sl.starttime
                    WHEN cl.createdate >= c1.modifieddate AND cl.createdate >= sl.starttime AND 
                    cl.createdate >= pr.created AND cl.createdate >= pm.created THEN 
                    cl.createdate
        WHEN pr.created >= c1.modifieddate AND pr.created >= sl.starttime AND 
                    pr.created >= cl.createdate AND pr.created >= pm.created THEN pr.created
        WHEN pm.created >= c1.modifieddate AND pm.created >= sl.starttime AND 
                    pm.created >= cl.createdate AND pm.created >= pr.created THEN pm.created
                    ELSE c1.modifieddate
            END AS MostRecentActivity
    FROM contacts c1
         left outer join serviceslabel sl on c1.contactid=sl.contactid
         left outer join calls cl on c1.contactid=cl.contactid
         left outer join procall pr on c1.contactid=pr.contactid
         left outer join pmpcall pm on c1.contactid=pm.contactid
) AS date_query
)
order by c1.lastname, c1.firstname
```

Comment: If by the tags `sql` and `server`, do you mean `sql-server`? If so, can update your post the version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: Yes, it is SQL Server.  I don't know why the tags separated since I wrote them in together.  I'll try to edit.

Comment: What about the version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Thomas--It's SQL-Server Enterprise Version 8.0.  I'll edit in the body of the question, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you post is too complex for us. Nobody will take the time to decypher it. However here is how you get all duplicate rows:

select *
from T
join (select col1, col2 from T group by col1, col2 having count(*) > 1) dups on T.col1 = dups.col1 and ...

The trick is to first find the duplicate "keys" and then find all rows which have one of the duplicate keys in them.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer and feedback. I'll try this way and perhaps repost a more simple query for the latest activity.

Comment: @usr--Got it now. It works to find the duplicates and I didn't know you could join like that.  Thanks!